Understanding the concept of work and potential energy
I'll be presenting an example to demonstrate my general misunderstanding.
Suppose a mass $m$ is sliding on an inclined plane of angle $\alpha$ downward, with no friction between the plane and the mass. Assuming there's a gravity force acting, then there's a normal force $N$ acting too s.t it has a component in $y$ direction (the vertical direction).
Why, when we compute the potential energy $U_y$ we only consider the gravitational force component in $y$ direction but ignore that of $N$? I think I misunderstand the concept of kinetic & potential energy since I thought we're taking:
$U_y =- \int \langle F_{tot} \space| \space \hat{y} \rangle d\hat{y}$
where $F_{tot}$ is sum of all forces vector aka the net force vector.
If someone could help me conceptualize it through this example and see it mathematically I'll be very glad.

Gravitational Potential Energy is defined using this: The work done by the gravitational force is equal to minus the change in gravitational potential energy.

And how does this align with the form of $U_y$ I presented above?

Your definition of potential energy is incorrect. For instance, non conservative forces cannot be written as the gradient of a potential function. So you have to define a separate U for each conservative force, and deal with non conservative forces (such as the normal) in some other way

And in this example particularly, why would this makes sense to omit the N force component in $\hat{y}$ direction?

$\int_{\vec s_A}^{\vec s_B} \vec F_{grav}\cdot d\vec s = - \Delta U_{grav} = -\left( (U_{grav}(\vec s_B) - (U_{grav}(\vec s_A) \right)$

@robphy I see but why shouldn't we do the same for $ F_{N,y} = \langle N | \hat{y} \rangle \hat{y}$?

For gravity and other conservative forces, the line integral is independent of the path. So we can define a potential energy function as a function of position in space. (So, the change in potential energy depends only on the endpoints, independent of path taken.)

@X4J "where $F_{tot}$ is sum of all forces vector aka the net force vector." Don't you mean the sum of all conservative forces?

Two points:

Because of the definition $$\tag1 \text {work}=\Delta \text{potential energy} =\bf F\cdot x$$ where $\bf F$ is the force ($\bf x$ is displacement), the work done would be zero. The direction of the normal force is perpendicular to the direction of the object's motion. That is, $$\bf N\cdot x=0$$ hence no work is done.


I thought we're taking:
$U_y =- \int \langle F_{tot} \space| \space \hat{y} \rangle d\hat{y}$


Note that the definition (1) above only holds when $\bf F$ is a conservative force. A potential energy function is associated with conservative forces exclusively.


I thought we're taking:
$U_y =- \int \langle F_{tot} \space| \space \hat{y} \rangle d\hat{y}$

This will only be true for the conservative component of the net force, $\bf F_g$.
Even though $F_{net}$ can be written as the sum of gravity and the normal force, it is only the gravity component of the work done (i.e., $\bf F_g\cdot\Delta h$) that can be written as the difference in the potential energy.
Normal forces are not conservative.
